# cannot assign value of type 'AASquaresLoading' in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got this error while compiling the project in in Xcode 8.2.1.

> cannot assign value of type 'AASquaresLoading' to type
>   'CAAnimationDelegate?'

[image]

Is there any solution to solve this error?

Comment: Does `AASquaresLoading` adopt the `CAAnimationDelegate` protocol?

Comment: dunno brother can we contact gmail? @vacawama

Comment: No. That violates the spirit of Stack Overflow.  Questions and answers are posted here to help others with the same issue.

Comment: Your `AASquaresLoading` should adopt the `CAAnimationDelegate` protocol.  Add `CAAnimationDelegate` to the `class` definition line: something like `class AASquaresLoading: CAAnimationDelegate`.  You'll probably have to implement some required methods if `CAAnimationDelegate` has any.

Comment: @vacawama am facing this error for 4 weeks now brother.

Comment: Edit your question to add relevant code (not pictures) for the AASquaresLoading class.

Comment: Working with someone one on one is not the best way to get to a solution.  Post the relevant data here and many eyes will look at it.

Comment: @vacawama class AASquaresLoading is already there.